# decode a transaction receipt which does not have an event log

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, web3.py, logs

Is there a way to decode a transaction receipt which does not have an event log? In the case of an event log we have topics which we can decode, but what about the case when an event isn't triggered when a transaction takes place, how will such a receipt be decoded?

An example is:

> AttributeDict({'blockHash':
> HexBytes('0x79c943cb77f647e0553a101d0c1df2d05645782b3a1ac8d3cabc593eb4fc3fa3'),
> 'blockNumber': 4605167, 'contractAddress': None, 'cumulativeGasUsed':
> 5980337, 'from': '0x52bc44d5378309EE2abF1539BF71dE1b7d7bE3b5',
> 'gasUsed': 21000, 'logs': [], 'logsBloom':
> HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'),
> 'status': 1, 'to': '0xDacEad08c11faCf6DFb53523fBf6A0f45864B97b',
> 'transactionHash':
> HexBytes('0xb1957a85976c18c5d1768dd5aad2c11cb079270e47f40262aefd6827a1106fc1'),
> 'transactionIndex': 69})

Since the address in **from** field is 0x52bc44d5378309EE2abF1539BF71dE1b7d7bE3b5 so I guess it will be counted as this addresses' transaction.

Comment: Please share the receipt, as well as the code of the relevant contract function.

Comment: I have added an example. However, I don't know if a contract is being called or not.

Comment: @mahamzaidi In provided receipt `to` is an external owned account (not an smart contract) so no event will be generated.

Comment: But I have read that it is isnt compulsory that a event is fired in a smart contract. It's up to the programmer.

Comment: @mahamzaidi Yes, that is correct a contract may decide to not generate any event. In that case there's nothing to decode. If you are trying to study internal transactions the only option is to use something like [`traceTransaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#debug_tracetransaction).

Comment: Okay. So it isn't possible at all for me to across a receipt which shows input/data field without event log.